# Given a date range, find events that overlap within that range

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, c#-4.0

Given a input date range, such as 11/1/2015 - 11/15/2015, what is the most efficient way to determine which events(CalendarEvents) are going on during that given date range.

```
event         eventStart     eventEnd
==================================
expo          10/25/2015    11/4/2015       //This should be selected.

concert       11/4/2014      11/5/2015      //This should be selected.

exhibit       11/15/2015     12/1/2015      //this should be selected.

display       10/26/2015    10/29/2015      //this should NOT be selected.
```

Linq or SQL server would be awesome.  Basically given a date range, find events that overlap within that range.

I know I could "brute force" with a bit of code, just wondering if I'm missing something more elegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StartA <= EndB AND EndA >= StartA` to get the overlapping dates:

```
DECLARE @startDate  DATE = '20151101',
        @endDate    DATE = '20151115'
SELECT * 
FROM CalendarEvents
WHERE
    eventStart <= @endDate
    AND eventEnd >= @startDate
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/110/0)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much!  I really have to cut myself off after 12 hours of coding from now on ;)

Comment: Don't forget the case where you have an event that completely covers your window. (e.g. 10/31-11/16 completely covers 11/1-11/15)